# Please help me prove that this equation has no solutions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals

$\sqrt{x^2+1}+\sqrt{x-1}=-3$.
 Been stuck on it for a while, having figured out nothing. After i raise both sides to the second power, i get an equation with x in 4 different powers, which i have no way of solving. Please do help if you can.

Comment: square roots are never negative ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The principle square root of any positive number is never negative, therefore the sum of two non-negative terms cannot be negative.

Comment: why is it a principal square root?

Comment: I mean why can't a square root of x^2 +1 be negative ? In that sense can't a square root of 4 be minus 2 ?

Comment: @j.jamesjonas That's just how square roots are defined. We want square roots to work like a function, so we don't want two possible values for the square root of 4. So we decided to set it to just 2.

Comment: It is in general if we have an equation $x^2 = a^2$ for $a \in \mathbb{R}$ then the solution to this equation is $x = \pm a$. i.e. there are two solutions to the equation, namely $x = \sqrt{a^2}$ or $x = - \sqrt{a^2}$. We must define the square-root function to be positive, for these two solutions to make sense (if we defined square root to have BOTH signs, then there isn't a point in having these two solutions.

Comment: oh, it makes sense now. Thanks.

Comment: It's a principal squar root because it is written as $\sqrt {stuff} $.  If they didn't mean the principal square root the shouldn't have used the symbol for principal squar root.  If they meant the negative square root the would have written $-\sqrt {stuff}$.  And if they meant *either* square root they would have written $\pm\sqrt {stuff} $.

Answer (score 5):

HINT

Square roots are never negative

Answer (score 0):

Note: $\sqrt{x} \ge 0,$   $\forall x \in \mathbb{R^+}$

Adding two non-negative numbers **cannot** result in a negative value.